# Task : To Create a Framework or SDK which could integrated into any iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

As i have never created a framework or sdk please guide on how to create it .

Push notification features

1) Different type of push notification(text,custom,image) handling on receive of push notification

2) Whenever a user receive push notification a request will be going to server that the particular user have recieved the notification and hence will not send that notification again to same user.

i just want to know which will be the best possible of creating this .
I have read about cocoa touch framework and cocoa touch static library.

At the end of this i have to get into one file just like in android we create .aar and share .

So i have concluded to to create Cocoa static library and then share it. or there is better way to proceed

Thanks

Comment: @Lu_ No....as in just want what is the right path....i have already did some searching...but not sure where to proceed –

Answer (score 1):

Static library are the only option for hiding your private classes.

If you dont need to hide anything you can opt for framework and directly import it in any project.

1) Start the project 
[image]

2) Put the file .a in your project in which you want to use 
[image]

Please go through this link if you face any import errors.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Hope it helps.